Second derivative of $y= xe^{x^2}$
$$y= xe^{x^2}$$
Taking natural log on both sides, $$ \ln y = x\times x^2 \ln e$$
$$\ln y = x^3$$
Differentiating both sides,
$$\frac{1}{y}y'=  3x^2\implies y'=3x^2y$$
Differentiating for a second time and using chain rule,
$$y''= 3x^2y' + 6xy$$
But the correct answer is $y''=4y+2xy'$.
Can someone tell me where I went wrong?

The logarithm of $xe^{x^2}$ is $\ln(x) + x^2$ ...

Your mistake is in the first step. The natural logarithm of $xe^{x^2} = \ln x+x^2$.
This is because:
$$\ln(xe^{x^2})=\ln x+\ln e^{x^2}$$
$$=\ln x+x^2\ln e$$
$$=\ln x+x^2$$

$\ln e^u=u,,,$

Why use ln function to find the derivative (as said in the title)? Thanks.

@NoChance There is no need for taking the natural log as the expression can be differentiated directly. I used $\ln$ here just to show where the computation error was made.

@J.W.Tanner Absolutely, I just wanted to show why that property was true as I think it's a fair assumption the original poster isn't too familiar with logarithm properties.

@Grey, thanks for your reply.

What did motivate the choice of taking the logarithm of the expression (which resulted in calculation error) ?
You can differentiate directly as well:
$y'=e^{x^2}+x(2x)e^{x^2}=\frac yx+2xy$
That you can rewrite $xy'=y+2x^2y$
Differentiating again gives $\require{cancel}xy''+\cancel{y'}=\cancel{y'}+4xy+2x^2y'$ and simplification by $x$ gives the result.

Observe that $y=u',$ where $u={1\over 2}e^{x^2}.$ Therefore we are after  the third derivative of $u.$ As $\log u=-\log 2+x^2$ then $\displaystyle {u'\over u}=2x,$ i.e. $u'=2xu.$ Therefore $$u''=2u+2xu'$$ $$u'''=2u'+2u'+2xu'' =4u'+2xu''$$ Hence $$y''=4y+2xy'$$
